# OpenBSD login.conf statement for nat-translated radius clients to ID as public address instead of private?

Tags: nat, radius, openbsd

I'm on OBSD6.0 behind a NAT firewall and attempting to authenticate against a RADIUS server on the outside. The RADIUS server gets the internal (private) address of the client system, not what the firewall NAT translates it to.
Is there a configuration statement that can inform the RADIUS server of the client's public address instead of it's private address?
I've tried local_address and remote_address with no luck.